# Cmake set option back to default

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I am building a C++ project using CMake on Windows. I have an option which is OFF by default and I'm overriding it to ON using CMake command line arguments. I build my project using the following commands:

```
cmake.exe --config "Release" . -DANALYSIS=ON
cmake.exe --build ./ -- /p:configuration=Release
```

If the option `ANALYSIS` is ON I do some additional things and want to set the `ANALYSIS` back to default value (OFF). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `ANALYSIS` to `OFF` from your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(ANALYSIS OFF CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
```

Using `set(<var> <value> CACHE ...)` without `FORCE` does not update cache variables, it's a no-op if the variable already exists.

It's also possible to remove `ANALYSIS`

```
unset(ANALYSIS CACHE)
```

You can still test it with `if(ANALYSIS)` which will give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The option `ANALYSIS` is cached in your `CMakeCache.txt` file. There are multiple ways how you can override the entry in your cache. For example use [ccmake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/ccmake.1.html) from the build directory to start interactive CMake GUI and modify the `ANALYSIS` option back to OFF.